# Firefox addon to display all shortcuts

Tags: browser, firefox-extensions, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a firefox addon that would display all shortcuts on a web page and also browser shortcuts.

for eg: c is the keyboard shortcut for gmail compose. So either on a particular key combination or by hovering over the compose button it should show a "c" to indicate there is a shortcut for this operation.

I guess If we keep on seeing the shortcuts popping each time when we do an action then we can start using and remembering more and more of it.

Thanks.

P.S:
If this is not the forum to ask this question please suggest appropriately in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The keyconfig extension from http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994 allows you to see (and modify) the keyboard shortcuts defined in Firefox. I haven't heard of a similar addon for shortcuts defined in web pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is not, the problem is that the shortcuts are hard coded, and any extension or application wanting to know them all, would have to read the source code and find them keyboard hooks, for web apps it could be done since the source code is visible, but it would be extremenly hard because javascript code sometime is ofuscated. Thou i agree with you, that would be a really good way to learn them, now for my possible answer:

For gmail you can ask in the gmail development google group, for the labs extensions, make a request, some dev might be interested, or of course you can code it your self using gmail's API.

Edit to include the url: http://groups.google.com/group/gmail-labs?pli=1

Comment: You might even be able to add them in yourself using Greasemonkey or even Stylish, depending on whether the "Compose" link etc. has an id or other reliable way to find it via a CSS selector or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try pressing **?**

Most sites with keyboard shortcuts also show a popup with those listed when a user presses the "Help" ? key (It's SHIFT + /, on my keyboard :P )

Guillermo is absolutely correct.